# SwiftUI SortDescriptor @State

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

I want to change the sortDescriptor with a button. 
But if I change the variables "sorting" and "sortOrder" to @State variables I get an Error.

The error-message is: *Variable 'self.fetchRequest' used before being initialized*

```swift
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    
@State var sorting: KeyPath = \Log.diveNr
@State var sortOrder: SortOrder = .forward
    
private var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Log>
private var logs: FetchedResults<Log> {
    fetchRequest.wrappedValue
}
    
init() {
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(sorting, order: sortOrder)])
}
```

Can someone help me to resolve this?

---

**SOLUTION:**

```swift
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.diveNr, order: .forward)])
    var logs: FetchedResults<Log>
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List{
                if logs.count == 0 {
                    Text("no Logs found")
                }
                Button("change order") {
                    logs.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\.diveNr, order: .reverse)]
                }
                ForEach(logs){log in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DiveLogDetailView(diveNo: 1, diveSite: "Vela Garska")) {
                        DiveLogListObject(log: log)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteLog)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set it in `body`. Unfortunately `@FetchRequest` is either badly designed or badly documented.

```
    func updateSort() {
        logs.sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\.diveNr, order: sortOrder)]
    }

    var body: some View {
        let _ = updateSort()
        NavigationStack {
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the use of `@State`, both `sorting` and `sortOrder` are computed properties. You cannot use a computed property in `init` until all stored properties have been initialized. (Otherwise, the computed property's getter might let the not-fully-initialized `self` escape.)

So use the underlying stored properties instead:

```
init() {
    let descriptor = SortDescriptor(
        _sorting.wrappedValue,
        order: _sortOrder.wrappedValue
    )
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [descriptor])
}
```

Comment: Now I don't get any errors anymore, but it's also not working :/

I added the current code above.
If I click on the Button it should change the sorting, but it's doing nothin.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `FetchRequest` as a property wrapper? Like `@FetchRequest private var fetchRequest: FetchedResults<Log>`

Comment: If I use it like this, then I get this error 
`Cannot assign to property: 'fetchRequest' is a get-only property`

But if there is another way i can fetch the entries and change the sorting later in the app I'm of course open to it.

Comment: I found a solution :)

... will post it shortly